# What is the functional difference between Entity Framework .Update() and Updating a field for a tracked entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Lets say I have an entity `Book` and a DbSet called `Books` in my `DbContext`.

The `Book` entity looks like this:

```cs
class Book 
{
    int Id { get; set; } //Id is the primary key
    string Title { get; set; }
    int Pages { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I want to update a book that already exists in my context:

```cs
var editingBook = async _context.Books.FindAsync(100);

// For simplicity's sake lets say that a Book with Id 100 exists and was retrieved
```

Is there a difference between updating the book in any of the following ways?

```cs
editingBook.title = 'New Title'
await _context.SaveAsync()
```

```cs
editingBook.title = 'New Title'
_context.Books.Update(editingBook);
await _context.SaveAsync();
```

It is my current assumption that the call for update would only be needed if we lost context somehow, for example if we got the book `.AsNoTracking()` or if we copied the values from `editingBook` into a new Book. In that case does Update try to find an existing book with the same primary ID to update in context?

Is there functionally a difference between using Update vs just Saving the current context when you still have tracking?

Edit: I understand that both of these work. I am not looking for instructions on how to update an entity in EF. I am looking for a peek into the functional difference of these two methods explained by someone with deep knowledge of EF and its inner workings.

Comment: Thanks @Jawad, just updated. All this code is hypothetical, but let's keep it accurate!

Comment: Difference betweek `SaveAsync` and `Update then SaveAsync` is the data being changed. If you only use `SaveAsync`, then only the changed values are updated. WIth `Update then SaveAsync`, you are updating the "entire" object.

Comment: Have you read the intellisense information provided by `Update`?

Comment: @Silvermind Yep! I understand what `Update` does I just wanted to better understand the difference between changing a tracked entity.

Comment: @Jawad so functionally the difference is under the hood? But behaviorally this will do the exact same thing?